# Basic Excel: Auto filling with exceptions

Tags: excel

I am a beginner at excel and I would like to ask a basic question.

I understand the basic idea of auto filling, but there is something more that I would like to do.

I am given two columns of numbers in each cell and on the third cell I want to calculate the number column1 - column2 then auto fill.

However, some of the cells in column1 and 2 are not numeric, and for the third column "# Value!" shows up for the corresponding rows.

I want those specific cells to say "N/A" instead.

Are there any standard ways to do such things?
What would professionals usually do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To subtract A from B with that exception, your formula in C1 can be

```
=if(iserror(b1-a1), "N/A", b1-a1)
```

A more specific solution to test whether both A and B are numeric is

```
=if(count(a1:b1)<2, "N/A", b1-a1)
```

Then autofill the formula down that column.

Comment: So, this is what I think is going on.  the "if" function basically says if b1-a1 is an error, "iserror(b1-a1)", then it gives us "N/A".  Otherwise, it becomes b1-a1.  Is the third argument optional?  What would happen if I do not write anything?

Could you briefly explain why the second one is more specific?  what does "count(a1:b1)<2" do?

Comment: the third argument is needed, it specifies the result for when the condition is not met. the count function checks if both cells have numeric value or not. If they do, the count result is 2, if one or both are not, the result is less than 2.

Comment: I tried =iferror(b1-a1,"N/A") and it basically showed what I wanted.  How is this different from what you have?

Comment: http://www.exceloogle.com/2013/06/functions-iferror-and-iserror.html this is a clear explanation of the difference